# Vector space span by one-to-one function

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

Consider $f$ be a one-to-one function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R.$ the question

> Can $f$ form a basis?

if so , $V=\text{span}_{\Bbb Q}(f)$ would be $1$-dimensional vector space. Notice that basis does not contain $0.$ So, we can take $f(x)=e^x$, from example. **Is that right** ?

Comment: "Can $f$ form a basis?" doesn't make sense until a vector space containing $f$ as an element is specified.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, thank for your comment and your right. I think I should ask like that . Is there a 1-dimensional vector that spans by a one-to-one function? Is it clear now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. More generally, any nonzero singleton in any vector space forms a basis of some subspace.